# Image animation - memory issues

Tags: image, animation, memory

I’m searching for the best and easiest way to animate images on iPhone.
I have about 75 images that needs to be animated in full screen when the user pushes a button.
I have tried:

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"], 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image6.png"],nil];        
imageView.animationDuration = 0.50;        
[imageView setAnimationRepeatCount: 1];        
[imageView startAnimating]; `
```

There is a little delay when the user pushes the button, but the animation runs great. The problem is that this method uses too much memory.

It’s not an option to use less or smaller images for the animations (I tried).
The images show a 3d movement so it’s not possible to just move, turn or flip the images.

I have been looking at OpenGL and Cocos2d but is that the right way to go?

I am looking forward to your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It uses a lot of memory because you are putting all the images into the array at once.

An alternative is to use a UIImageView and set it's image property with animation, but don't use the imageNamed method to get the image, as there is cacheing involved. You should alloc / init them and nil them when done.

Comment: Do you have an example that shows how this can be done?

The user can push the button more then once and the animations must run without delay. Is that possible in the way you describe?